# C++ memory leak after main finishes?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

is this a memory leak?, supposed Foo() is a class with a default constructor

```
int main()
{

   Foo * p = new Foo();

   return 0;
}
```

I think it is not a leak because the application ends as soon as main ends and supposedly the OS releases all the resources for that app once it is done. Is that assumption right?

Comment: Yes that is correct for most OSes.

Comment: What's wrong with `Foo p;`. Then the object is destroyed automatically when you leave the scope.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in the context of your program it is a leak. You did not de-allocate your `Foo`.

Will your OS reclaim the process's memory anyway? Maybe, maybe not. Windows will re-use the memory, sure.

But if you want a general-purpose hyper-practical answer for your system and your system only then, yes, you might get away with this.

However, in no cases will indirect resources be magically freed by your OS. **`Foo`'s destructor may involve more than memory de-allocation**.

If you want a C++ answer, or one that has merit in terms of code integrity, intelligent design <sup>(lol)</sup> and frankly simply good habits, *no*. When someone asks for solid practical reasons that they *must find a reason* to do `delete`, it can be hard to justify when forced to provide examples such as file handles, network connections, and worker threads. But basic common sense dictates that all of these concerns are *automatically taken care of*, **without you having to name each one individually**, when you simply take the 5-second effort to destroy your objects when you're done with them.

Just `delete` it. You have no excuse not to.

Comment: elaborate on "as long as Foo's destructor doesn't have further resources to free"

Comment: @BWG: `struct Foo { char* ptr; int fd, fd2; Foo() : ptr(new char[50000000]), fd(open("/tmp/moronic", O_CREATE | O_APPEND)), fd2(someTcpConnectionFunction("google.com", 80)) {}; }; int main() { new Foo(); } // WHOOPS`

Comment: wait... doesn't the OS free the chars as well?

Comment: any OS that would free the initial Foo

Comment: @BWG: Take one more look.

Comment: I find that kind of hard to believe. I'd guess it is more difficult to free a connection than a few spare bytes, but doesn't the OS know? Could I put that in a `while(1)` loop and totally destroy my computer's memory (temporarily)?

Comment: nonono I didn't mean it in that respect. It was just contrary to what I believed, and I frankly find it alarming. Sorry if I sounded like a skeptic, I didn't mean it to come across that way.

Comment: @BWG I think you're missing the fact that his constructor is also opening a file.  What if the object in question opens network sockets or database connections?  What if it creates a lock file on disk?  Anything meaningful that might be implemented in Foo::~Foo() will NOT happen if you don't delete the object.  Memory that is allocated will be reclaimed by the OS on most platforms, but there are resources other than memory.